# Is "exemplary punishment" applicable in modern legal systems?

Tags: law

I have been looking for references but I could not find any.  Wikipedia does not have an article for "exemplary punishment", and the word "exemplary" cannot be found in the article for "punishment".  Dictionaries state what exemplary punishment is, without stating anything about its applicability in modern societies.

So, the question is:

Is exemplary punishment practiced by or called for by the legal systems of modern progressive nations? Can a judge legitimately speak of imposing an exemplary punishment on a criminal? Or is exemplary punishment a concept only espoused by authoritarian, oppressive regimes?

When people call for the exemplary punishment of a criminal today, are they being callous? Are they missing the real meaning of the term?

EDIT: from [dictionary.reverso.net](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/exemplary%20%5Bof%20a%20punishment%5D) adj An exemplary punishment is unusually harsh and is intended to stop other people from committing similar crimes. "He demanded exemplary sentences for those behind the violence."

Comment: What is exemplary punishment?

Comment: Do you mean things equivalent to "cruel and *unusual* punishments," such as is currently prohibited by the 4th Amendment to the US Constitution?

Comment: @AffableGeek 8th amendment

Comment: Yeah, like I said, 8th amendment. :). Good thing google can't do an unreasonable search of the comments.

Comment: Since when does ignorance of a term constitute reason for a down-vote? I have added an explanation of what exemplary punishment means, which you could have also found in dictionaries.

Comment: An exemplary punishment does not necessarily have to be so severe as to be provable in a U.S. court as "cruel and unusual" as per U.S. constitution, but then again I do not know, perhaps U.S. judges specifically refrain from using the term because maybe there is legal precedent equating it with cruel and unusual punishment, so, that's part of what I am asking to find out.  Also, the world is not the U.S., so the state of affairs in other developed countries of the world is also of interest.

Comment: Your question was, prior to the edit, highly ambiguous, and hence Downvote worthy imho. Your edit is in the right direction, but as your first answer shows, is highly culture dependent, and hence a poor fit for an international forum such as this. I see no reason to retract my -1.

Comment: The fact that you couldn't find a dictionary definition or Wikipedia page should have been a signal that some clarification was in order.

Comment: Looking up "deterrence" instead of "exemplary" will answer the majority of this question.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the functions of punishment everywhere (together with “revenge” and “retribution”), except that it is usually discussed under more technical-sounding names like “deterrence”. It is still being intensively studied and debated.

Usually, a judge probably wouldn't justify a decision by referring to its “exemplary value” (or, in fact, to any other functions of punishment), but it is baked into the criminal code. That's perhaps where the difference with traditional societies lies; [*Nullum crimen, nulla poena sine praevia lege poenali*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullum_crimen,_nulla_poena_sine_praevia_lege_poenali) is an important principle in modern legal systems (sometimes attributed to Cesare Beccaria). Thus, individual judges cannot suddenly decide to impose some harsh punishment because a crime seems abhorrent if there is no legal basis for this punishment.

The punishments are also typically gradual for the same reason. If you risk the most severe punishment for property crimes, you would have no incentive not to kill victims or witnesses to cover up such crimes. Generally premeditated killing (“first-degree murder” in the US) is one of the most serious crimes and severe punishment (e.g. decades-long imprisonment) does serve as a deterrent.

Of course, what's acceptable for this purpose varies a lot across times and cultures. Public executions and torture were once common in Europe but would seem barbaric today (although they are still occasionally practiced elsewhere). The death penalty has mostly been abolished in Europe but is still commonly practiced elsewhere in the world and often argued to have a deterrent effect in the US. Lifelong imprisonment is still common in most of Europe but considered inhumane in some Scandinavian countries.